# Draw a smooth closed path with tikz ( the simplest way )

Tags: tikz-pgf, metapost

I have this fragment of matapost code which  draw  a smooth curve through points using `..` operation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mpgraphics} 
\begin{document} 

\begin{mpdisplay}
z0 = (0,0);
z1 = (60,40);
z2 = (40,90);
z3 = (10,70);
z4 = (30,50);
path p;
p = z0..z1..z2..z3..z4..cycle;
draw p; 
\end{mpdisplay}

\end{document}
```

Which produce a nice closed smooth line ( compiled with `pdflatex --shell-escape` )

[image]

I would like to draw the above picture with `tikz`, and I do not want to use `..controls` operation. I want the simplest way to draw a smooth closed line such as the picture.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `hobby` package (or TikZ library):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
  \path
  (0,0) coordinate (z0)
  (60,40) coordinate (z1)
  (40,90) coordinate (z2)
  (10,70) coordinate (z3)
  (30,50) coordinate (z4);
  \draw[closed] (z0) .. (z1) .. (z2) .. (z3) .. (z4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```