# Ghost shape in TikZ/pgf

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun

**My question**

I can easily draw the normal distribution thanks to [this answer by Jake](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11368/bell-curve-gaussian-function-normal-distribution-in-tikz-pgf). What about the ghost ?

[image]

**Context**

This image always breaks the ice when teaching probabilities :)

(Not that I care so much about it, but Halloween is getting closer too)

I presume it would be possible with Inkscape (but I am not familiar with it).

[This answer by Paul Gaborit](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357603/draw-a-smooth-closed-path-with-tikz-the-simplest-way) uses the `hobby` package I tried to adapt (poorly as you'll see, far too manual to be honnest) in my MWE.

I'd be happy to see different approaches too (pure tikz, pgfplot, other libraries...).

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]

\draw[
  help lines,
  line width=0.1pt,
  blue,
] (-20, -20) grid[step={($(5, 5) - (0, 0)$)}] (60, 100);

  \path
  (0,0) coordinate (z0)
  (10,10) coordinate (z1)
  (20,0) coordinate (z2)
  (30,10) coordinate (z3)
  (40,0) coordinate (z4)
  (50,10) coordinate (z5)
  (30,90) coordinate (z6)
  (0,70) coordinate (z7)
  (0,60) coordinate (z8)
;
  \draw[closed,black, line width= 3mm] (z0) .. (z1) .. (z2)  .. (z3) .. (z4) .. (z5).. (z6).. (z7).. (z8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Seeing that it's been 11 hours and no one else has nitpicked yet, I just had to remark that putting the two images side by side, could be seen as implying that the "Paranormal distribution" is also expected to be a 2d plot of a single variable probability density function, but of course it's not a function, with multiple y values for the same x. Therefore, to avoid any such confusion, I would recommend that we instead treat the "Paranormal Distribution" as a joint (bivariate) density function, which then has the added benefit of giving you a good reason to include colors ;)

Comment: @yoniLavi a pgf answer that looks promising!

Comment: @yoniLavi [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/m/n8ttgf35) gives an idea on how to a a achieve an answer with `pgfplot`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This is my attempt, using Ti*k*Z and a lot of `to[out=...,in=...]`s.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,line cap=round]
  % grid
  %\draw[gray] (-5,0) grid[step=0.5] (5,13);
  % ghost 'body'
  \draw[line width=0.75mm] (0,1.5) to[out=0,in=180] (1.5,0)
    to[out=0  ,in=180] (3,2) to[out=0,in=135] (4,1.5)
    to[out=-45,in=-45,looseness=2] (4.5,2) 
    to[out=135,in=270] (3,8)
    to[out=90 ,in=90 ,looseness=2.5] (-3,8)
    to[out=270,in=45] (-4.5,2)
    to[out=225,in=225,looseness=2] (-4,1.5)
    to[out=45 ,in=180] (-3,2)
    to[out=0  ,in=180] (-1.5,0)
    to[out=0  ,in=180] (0,1.5);
  % ghost eyes
  \foreach\i in {-1,1}
  {%
    \begin{scope}[shift={(\i-0.3,8.5)},rotate=\i*10]
      \fill ellipse (0.3 cm and 0.6 cm);
    \end{scope}}
  % axis
  \draw (-5.5,-1) -- (5.5,-1);
  \foreach\i in {-5,...,5}
    \draw (\i,-1) --++ (0,-0.2);
  \node at (0,-2) {\huge\bfseries Paranormal Distribution};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the ghost:
[image]

**Edit.** An animated ghost:

```
\documentclass    {beamer}
\usepackage       {tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[thick,line cap=round,scale=0.5]
  \useasboundingbox (-8,0) rectangle (8,14);
  % fake normal distribution
  \foreach\j in {1,...,5}
  {%
    \pgfmathtruncatemacro\jj{20-\j}
    \only<\j,\jj>
    {%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\y{0.2*(10-\j)}
      \draw plot[domain=-8:8,samples=81,smooth] (\x*\y,{13/(1+0.07*\x*\x)});
    }
  }
  % ghost
  \foreach\j in {6,...,14}
  {%
    \only<\j>
    {%
      \pgfmathsetmacro\y{0.05*abs(10-\j)}
      % ghost 'body'
      \coordinate (A) at (0,1.5+\y);
      \coordinate (B) at (1.5,0);
      \coordinate (C) at (3,2+\y);
      \coordinate (D) at (4,1.5);
      \coordinate (E) at (4.5,2);
      \coordinate (F) at (-4.5,2);
      \coordinate (G) at (-4,1.5);
      \coordinate (H) at (-3,2+\y);
      \coordinate (I) at (-1.5,0);
      \draw[line width=0.5mm] (A) to[out=0,in=180] (B)
        to[out=0  ,in=180] (C) to[out=0,in=135] (D)
        to[out=-45,in=-45,looseness=2] (E)
        to[out=135,in=270] (3,8)
        to[out=90 ,in=90,looseness=2.5] (-3,8)
        to[out=270,in=45] (F)
        to[out=225,in=225,looseness=2] (G)
        to[out=45 ,in=180] (H)
        to[out=0  ,in=180] (I)
        to[out=0  ,in=180] (A);
      % ghost eyes
      \foreach\i in {-1,1}
      {%
        \begin{scope}[shift={(\i-3*\y,8.5)},rotate=\i*10]
          \fill ellipse (0.3cm and 0.6cm);
        \end{scope}
      }
    }
  }
  % axis
  \draw (-8.5,-1) -- (8.5,-1);
  \foreach\i in {-8,...,8}
    \draw (\i,-1) --++ (0,-0.2);
  \node at (0,-2) {\huge\bfseries\strut
    \only<8-12>{p}%
    \only<7-13>{a}%
    \only<6-14>{r}%
    \only<5-15>{a}%
    normal distribution\strut};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice !!!! really...

Comment: @JeT, thanks!! ;-)

Comment: This is exceptional work!! +1

Comment: @VScode_fanboy, thanks!!

Comment: Spectacular ahahahah...LOL :-)

Comment: How does the ghost look sad without even a mouth (or is it just me)?  Also we need a ghost for TikZpeople

Comment: Impressive....ahahahaahah....

Comment:  for your edit :)

Comment: @ChrisH It is sad on the question as well lol.

Answer (score 22):

You could use the ghost from halloweenmath

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{halloweenmath,graphicx}
\begin{document}
\resizebox{4cm}{!}{$\mathghost$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Funny font indeed. I'd be happy to see how TikZ can actually handle this ghosty shape :) As an exercice I could work on.

Comment: do you know how to compile the same ghost but without the eyes?

Comment: @ÁlvaroA.Gutiérrez-Vargas there is no interface, but you can do `\makeatletter
\resizebox{4cm}{!}{\def\@HwM@symm@ghost@eyes#1#2#3{}$\mathghost$}
\makeatother`

Answer (score 17):

A quick suggestion with pure tikz:

```
\documentclass[border=6.66mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[smooth cycle]
        
        \draw[] plot[tension=1]
        coordinates{(0,0)  (1,1) (2,0) (3,1) (4,0) (4,4) (3,9) (0,2) (0,1)};
        
        %eyes
        \draw[fill=black,rotate around={-45:(2.3,7)}] (2.3,7) ellipse (2mm and 3.5mm);
        \draw[fill=black,rotate around={-45:(3.3,7)}] (3.3,7) ellipse (2mm and 3.5mm);
        
        %mouth [optional]
        \draw[fill=black,rotate around={-10:(3,5)}] (3,5) arc (0:-180:0.5cm and 3mm);
        
        \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

> With four parameters I can fit an elephant, and with five I can make him wiggle his trunk.
> *John von Neumann*

The trick with `hobby` is to start with a few points on the shape and then add more points where the curve deviates from the one wanted.  The more points, the more specific the curve.  With the ghost, the wiggly bottom edge clearly needs several points, and then there needs to be another on each side just above the bottom edge to get the sides under control, but the rest of the sides doesn't need any more points.

I used [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9559/86) to define a coordinate system overlaying the original image to place the points.  I've left this code in the document below (commented out).  This does mean that the coordinates are specified on a small scale (since the coordinate system goes from `(0,0)` to `(1,1)`) but a suitable `scale=20` fixes that.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/618136/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{hobby}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[use Hobby shortcut]
%\node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt] at (0,0) (ghost) {\includegraphics{ghost.png}};
%\begin{scope}[x={(ghost.south east)},y={(ghost.north west)}]
%\draw[blue,ultra thin] (.3,.1) grid[step=.01] (.7,.6);
%\draw[blue,ultra thick] (0,0) grid[step=.1] (1,1);
\begin{scope}[scale=20]
\draw[ultra thick]
([closed].5,.52) ..
(.6,.28) ..
(.625,.22) ..
(.6,.21) ..
(.58,.22) ..
(.55,.17) ..
(.5,.21) ..
(.45,.17) ..
(.43,.21) ..
(.39,.195) ..
(.4,.26)
;

\fill[black] (.515,.425) ellipse[x radius=.01, y radius=.02];
\fill[black] (.47,.425) ellipse[x radius=.01, y radius=.02];

    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: hobby ghost one]

To make the top a little more curved, add points at `(.53,.51)` and `(.47,.51)` either side of the point at `(.5,.52)`.

[image: hobby ghost two]

Comment: Nice nice....very nice...ghost....LOL :-)

Comment: @Andrew Impressive. Very clear explations. The TikZ over an image solves my poor attempt. I steal your VN quote :)

Answer (score 9):

A crazy ghost from the hell of the package `twemojis`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{twemojis,scalerel}
\begin{document}
\scaleobj{15}{\twemoji{ghost}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I like yours too!!! XD

Comment: @JuanCastaño Your ghost is simply excellent. LOL :-)))))

Comment: @Sebastiano Merci ! I think your addenda deserves a separate answer :)

Comment: @JeT I provide now :-)...you're very welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Other ghost symbols from `fontawesome5` and another done with `TikZ`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\textcolor{GhostWhite}{\fontsize{70}{60}\selectfont \faGhost}
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand{\ghost}[1]{\tikz[baseline=.2em,scale=8]{
  \draw [fill=#1] (0,0) -- (0,.5) arc (+180:0:.3) -- (.6,0) --
  (.5,.15) -- (.4,0) -- (.3,.15) -- (.2,0) -- (.1,.15) -- cycle;
    \coordinate (visual) at (360*rand:.03);
    \foreach \x in {.15,.4}{
    \fill[black] (\x,.5) ++(visual) circle[radius=.07];
    }}}

\begin{document}
\ghost{white}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That second one is just begging for a pac-man.

Comment: @Hearth Hi.....yes you're right...I have thought to the Pac-Man game :-))))) See this link:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghosts_(Pac-Man)

Answer (score 4):

---

Another suggestion is to convert your ghost in `.svg` and export in `LaTeX` making some changes: https://products.aspose.app/pdf/it/conversion/svg-to-tex. Here I have improved a bit the (**very long**) original code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
 \path (0,0);
\filldraw[black][nonzero rule]
(176.7pt, -0.499985pt) .. controls (186.5pt, -5.399994pt) and (194.8pt, -17.09999pt) .. (198.3pt, -30.99998pt)
 -- (198.3pt, -30.99998pt)
 -- (198.3pt, -30.99998pt)
 -- (198.3pt, -30.99998pt) .. controls (199.2pt, -34.59999pt) and (200.7pt, -44.7pt) .. (201.6pt, -53.5pt)
 -- (201.6pt, -53.5pt)
 -- (201.6pt, -53.5pt)
 -- (201.6pt, -53.5pt) .. controls (204.3pt, -81.5pt) and (209.4pt, -99.8pt) .. (222.7pt, -129.8pt)
 -- (222.7pt, -129.8pt)
 -- (222.7pt, -129.8pt)
 -- (222.7pt, -129.8pt) .. controls (229.9pt, -146.2pt) and (230.6pt, -150.9pt) .. (226.5pt, -153.6pt)
 -- (226.5pt, -153.6pt)
 -- (226.5pt, -153.6pt)
 -- (226.5pt, -153.6pt) .. controls (223.3pt, -155.7pt) and (219.4pt, -155pt) .. (214pt, -151.4pt)
 -- (214pt, -151.4pt)
 -- (214pt, -151.4pt)
 -- (214pt, -151.4pt) .. controls (208.6pt, -147.8pt) and (205.6pt, -149pt) .. (204.6pt, -155pt)
 -- (204.6pt, -155pt)
 -- (204.6pt, -155pt)
 -- (204.6pt, -155pt) .. controls (203.5pt, -162.1pt) and (200pt, -171.4pt) .. (197.8pt, -173.3pt)
 -- (197.8pt, -173.3pt)
 -- (197.8pt, -173.3pt)
 -- (197.8pt, -173.3pt) .. controls (196.7pt, -174.2pt) and (194.2pt, -175pt) .. (192.3pt, -175pt)
 -- (192.3pt, -175pt)
 -- (192.3pt, -175pt)
 -- (192.3pt, -175pt) .. controls (188.5pt, -175pt) and (188.1pt, -174.6pt) .. (177.2pt, -162.2pt)
 -- (177.2pt, -162.2pt)
 -- (177.2pt, -162.2pt)
 -- (177.2pt, -162.2pt) .. controls (170.3pt, -154.3pt) and (168.6pt, -153.7pt) .. (162.4pt, -156.6pt)
 -- (162.4pt, -156.6pt)
 -- (162.4pt, -156.6pt)
 -- (162.4pt, -156.6pt) .. controls (160.5pt, -157.5pt) and (156.7pt, -161.1pt) .. (153.9pt, -164.6pt)
 -- (153.9pt, -164.6pt)
 -- (153.9pt, -164.6pt)
 -- (153.9pt, -164.6pt) .. controls (148.4pt, -171.5pt) and (146.5pt, -173pt) .. (142.7pt, -173pt)
 -- (142.7pt, -173pt)
 -- (142.7pt, -173pt)
 -- (142.7pt, -173pt) .. controls (138.9pt, -173pt) and (136.9pt, -169.9pt) .. (136.3pt, -162.8pt)
 -- (136.3pt, -162.8pt)
 -- (136.3pt, -162.8pt)
 -- (136.3pt, -162.8pt) .. controls (136pt, -159.3pt) and (135.3pt, -155.7pt) .. (134.8pt, -154.7pt)
 -- (134.8pt, -154.7pt)
 -- (134.8pt, -154.7pt)
 -- (134.8pt, -154.7pt) .. controls (133.4pt, -151.9pt) and (128.5pt, -152.7pt) .. (120.1pt, -157pt)
 -- (120.1pt, -157pt)
 -- (120.1pt, -157pt)
 -- (120.1pt, -157pt) .. controls (111.4pt, -161.5pt) and (109.1pt, -161.8pt) .. (106.6pt, -159.1pt)
 -- (106.6pt, -159.1pt)
 -- (106.6pt, -159.1pt)
 -- (106.6pt, -159.1pt) .. controls (103.8pt, -156pt) and (105.3pt, -150.9pt) .. (114pt, -133pt)
 -- (114pt, -133pt)
 -- (114pt, -133pt)
 -- (114pt, -133pt) .. controls (118.4pt, -124.2pt) and (122.6pt, -114.6pt) .. (123.5pt, -111.7pt)
 -- (123.5pt, -111.7pt)
 -- (123.5pt, -111.7pt)
 -- (123.5pt, -111.7pt) .. controls (126.9pt, -100.1pt) and (130.3pt, -74pt) .. (131.5pt, -50.29999pt)
 -- (131.5pt, -50.29999pt)
 -- (131.5pt, -50.29999pt)
 -- (131.5pt, -50.29999pt) .. controls (132.5pt, -30.29999pt) and (137.6pt, -16.29999pt) .. (147.4pt, -6.499985pt)
 -- (147.4pt, -6.499985pt)
 -- (147.4pt, -6.499985pt)
 -- (147.4pt, -6.499985pt) .. controls (156pt, 2.100006pt) and (166.9pt, 4.300003pt) .. (176.7pt, -0.499985pt) -- cycle
(157.7pt, 2.600006pt) .. controls (145.1pt, -2.099991pt) and (135.2pt, -15.59999pt) .. (131.4pt, -33.39999pt)
 -- (131.4pt, -33.39999pt)
 -- (131.4pt, -33.39999pt)
 -- (131.4pt, -33.39999pt) .. controls (130.6pt, -37.29999pt) and (129.5pt, -47.89999pt) .. (129pt, -57pt)
 -- (129pt, -57pt)
 -- (129pt, -57pt)
 -- (129pt, -57pt) .. controls (127.6pt, -81.4pt) and (124.9pt, -100.2pt) .. (120.9pt, -113pt)
 -- (120.9pt, -113pt)
 -- (120.9pt, -113pt)
 -- (120.9pt, -113pt) .. controls (119.7pt, -116.6pt) and (115.8pt, -125.3pt) .. (112pt, -132.5pt)
 -- (112pt, -132.5pt)
 -- (112pt, -132.5pt)
 -- (112pt, -132.5pt) .. controls (108.3pt, -139.7pt) and (104.7pt, -148.1pt) .. (104pt, -151.3pt)
 -- (104pt, -151.3pt)
 -- (104pt, -151.3pt)
 -- (104pt, -151.3pt) .. controls (102.8pt, -156.7pt) and (102.8pt, -157.3pt) .. (104.7pt, -159.8pt)
 -- (104.7pt, -159.8pt)
 -- (104.7pt, -159.8pt)
 -- (104.7pt, -159.8pt) .. controls (107.8pt, -164pt) and (111.6pt, -163.8pt) .. (120.6pt, -159pt)
 -- (120.6pt, -159pt)
 -- (120.6pt, -159pt)
 -- (120.6pt, -159pt) .. controls (125.3pt, -156.5pt) and (129.4pt, -155pt) .. (130.9pt, -155.2pt)
 -- (130.9pt, -155.2pt)
 -- (130.9pt, -155.2pt)
 -- (130.9pt, -155.2pt) .. controls (133.4pt, -155.5pt) and (133.5pt, -155.9pt) .. (134.2pt, -162.8pt)
 -- (134.2pt, -162.8pt)
 -- (134.2pt, -162.8pt)
 -- (134.2pt, -162.8pt) .. controls (135pt, -171.8pt) and (137.3pt, -175pt) .. (143.1pt, -175pt)
 -- (143.1pt, -175pt)
 -- (143.1pt, -175pt)
 -- (143.1pt, -175pt) .. controls (147.2pt, -175pt) and (149.7pt, -173.1pt) .. (156.4pt, -164.7pt)
 -- (156.4pt, -164.7pt)
 -- (156.4pt, -164.7pt)
 -- (156.4pt, -164.7pt) .. controls (160.5pt, -159.7pt) and (164.5pt, -157pt) .. (167.8pt, -157pt)
 -- (167.8pt, -157pt)
 -- (167.8pt, -157pt)
 -- (167.8pt, -157pt) .. controls (168.9pt, -157pt) and (171.9pt, -159.4pt) .. (174.6pt, -162.4pt)
 -- (174.6pt, -162.4pt)
 -- (174.6pt, -162.4pt)
 -- (174.6pt, -162.4pt) .. controls (177.3pt, -165.3pt) and (181.4pt, -169.8pt) .. (183.7pt, -172.4pt)
 -- (183.7pt, -172.4pt)
 -- (183.7pt, -172.4pt)
 -- (183.7pt, -172.4pt) .. controls (187.5pt, -176.5pt) and (188.4pt, -177pt) .. (192.2pt, -177pt)
 -- (192.2pt, -177pt)
 -- (192.2pt, -177pt)
 -- (192.2pt, -177pt) .. controls (194.6pt, -177pt) and (197.5pt, -176.3pt) .. (198.6pt, -175.5pt)
 -- (198.6pt, -175.5pt)
 -- (198.6pt, -175.5pt)
 -- (198.6pt, -175.5pt) .. controls (201.3pt, -173.7pt) and (204.5pt, -166.2pt) .. (206pt, -158.2pt)
 -- (206pt, -158.2pt)
 -- (206pt, -158.2pt)
 -- (206pt, -158.2pt) .. controls (206.7pt, -154.8pt) and (207.6pt, -151.7pt) .. (208pt, -151.5pt)
 -- (208pt, -151.5pt)
 -- (208pt, -151.5pt)
 -- (208pt, -151.5pt) .. controls (208.5pt, -151.2pt) and (211.4pt, -152.4pt) .. (214.5pt, -154pt)
 -- (214.5pt, -154pt)
 -- (214.5pt, -154pt)
 -- (214.5pt, -154pt) .. controls (221.2pt, -157.5pt) and (223.4pt, -157.7pt) .. (227.9pt, -154.9pt)
 -- (227.9pt, -154.9pt)
 -- (227.9pt, -154.9pt)
 -- (227.9pt, -154.9pt) .. controls (231.2pt, -152.9pt) and (231.2pt, -152.8pt) .. (230.8pt, -147.2pt)
 -- (230.8pt, -147.2pt)
 -- (230.8pt, -147.2pt)
 -- (230.8pt, -147.2pt) .. controls (230.5pt, -143pt) and (228.9pt, -138.3pt) .. (224.6pt, -129.1pt)
 -- (224.6pt, -129.1pt)
 -- (224.6pt, -129.1pt)
 -- (224.6pt, -129.1pt) .. controls (218.1pt, -115.1pt) and (210pt, -91.9pt) .. (207.1pt, -78.5pt)
 -- (207.1pt, -78.5pt)
 -- (207.1pt, -78.5pt)
 -- (207.1pt, -78.5pt) .. controls (206pt, -73.5pt) and (204.4pt, -62.09999pt) .. (203.5pt, -53pt)
 -- (203.5pt, -53pt)
 -- (203.5pt, -53pt)
 -- (203.5pt, -53pt) .. controls (202.6pt, -43.89999pt) and (201.2pt, -33.79999pt) .. (200.4pt, -30.49998pt)
 -- (200.4pt, -30.49998pt)
 -- (200.4pt, -30.49998pt)
 -- (200.4pt, -30.49998pt) .. controls (196.8pt, -16.49998pt) and (188pt, -3.799988pt) .. (178.4pt, 1.000015pt)
 -- (178.4pt, 1.000015pt)
 -- (178.4pt, 1.000015pt)
 -- (178.4pt, 1.000015pt) .. controls (172.5pt, 3.900009pt) and (163.2pt, 4.700012pt) .. (157.7pt, 2.600006pt) -- cycle
;
\filldraw[black][nonzero rule]
(149.4pt, -35.49998pt) .. controls (147pt, -39.2pt) and (146pt, -45.89999pt) .. (147.1pt, -50.29999pt)
 -- (147.1pt, -50.29999pt)
 -- (147.1pt, -50.29999pt)
 -- (147.1pt, -50.29999pt) .. controls (149.1pt, -57.89999pt) and (153.9pt, -55.5pt) .. (156.1pt, -45.59999pt)
 -- (156.1pt, -45.59999pt)
 -- (156.1pt, -45.59999pt)
 -- (156.1pt, -45.59999pt) .. controls (158.2pt, -35.89999pt) and (153.7pt, -28.99998pt) .. (149.4pt, -35.49998pt) -- cycle
;
\filldraw[black][nonzero rule]
(172.6pt, -35.2pt) .. controls (169.3pt, -39.79999pt) and (171.6pt, -53.89999pt) .. (175.8pt, -55.5pt)
 -- (175.8pt, -55.5pt)
 -- (175.8pt, -55.5pt)
 -- (175.8pt, -55.5pt) .. controls (180.1pt, -57.09999pt) and (182.4pt, -47.09999pt) .. (179.5pt, -39.49998pt)
 -- (179.5pt, -39.49998pt)
 -- (179.5pt, -39.49998pt)
 -- (179.5pt, -39.49998pt) .. controls (177.3pt, -33.7pt) and (174.7pt, -32.09999pt) .. (172.6pt, -35.2pt) -- cycle
;
\draw    (15,233) -- (323,233) (46,229) -- (46,237)(77,229) -- (77,237)(108,229) -- (108,237)(139,229) -- (139,237)(170,229) -- (170,237)(201,229) -- (201,237)(232,229) -- (232,237)(263,229) -- (263,237)(294,229) -- (294,237) ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

My (very) improvable attempt with `pgfplot`.

Thanks to all the great previous answers and [Geogebra](https://www.geogebra.org/m/n8ttgf35), It helped me having a more precise idea.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.17}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
        countour/.style={line width=1.5pt,domain=-2.5:2.95},
        eyes/.style={scale=0.6,ellipse,fill=black,minimum height=10pt,,rotate=90},
        declare function={
            wave(\x) = 0.05 * sin(260*\x) -0.03 ; 
            Gauss(\x) = 1/(sqrt(2*pi))*exp(-0.5*(pow(\x,2))); 
        }
    ]
    \begin{axis}[samples = 100]
        \addplot[countour] {Gauss(x)};
        \addplot[countour] {wave(x)};
        \node[eyes]  at (axis cs:-0.4, 0.23) {aa} ;    
        \node[eyes]  at (axis cs:0.4, 0.23) {aa} ;    
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very very nice :-))))